# Why doesn't Wolfram Workbench work on 64-bit Ubuntu?

Tags: installation

I have downloaded the shell script (Workbench_2.0.0_LINUX.sh), I have run it as root with it giving no complaints, relevant looking files have appeared in `/usr/local/Wolfram/WolframWorkbench/2.0/` and it has created the executable "WolframWorkbench" in `/usr/local/bin`.

However, when I run `WolframWorkbench` from terminal it spits out

```
/usr/local/bin/WolframWorkbench: 46: exec: /usr/local/Wolfram/WolframWorkbench/2.0/WolframWorkbench: not found
```

That file does indeed exist, and is executable. I have also tried running it directly, and I have also tried running the `/usr/local/Wolfram/WolframWorkbench/2.0/Executables/WolframWorkbench` too. Is there something I'm missing?

(I am running Ubuntu 12.04 64bit with openjdk7)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a 32-bit executable which requires the `ia32-libs` compatibility package on 64-bit Ubuntu. Fix your problem with the below and then try running it again:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Comment: that was the problem! I should have posted earlier, I wasted too much time trying to figure this out.

Comment: Unfortunately, unless you already know about it, only using `strace` to execute will tell you *why* the file is "not found" :)